# Accessing char pointer fields in a structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a `struct` defined as

```
typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    char* ID;
    int marks;

    char* details;

} Student;
```

And another as

```
typedef struct
{
    int n;
    Student* stud_array;
} Batch;
```

A file has entries of various batches of student in a particular format, and I'm reading from that file to populate `BatchArray` of type `Batch*`

After each field is populated I am using

```
puts(BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].name);
puts(BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].ID);
printf("%d\n",BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].marks);
```

to see the result. And it gives me the right output.

However, after everything is done, when I want to iterate through `BatchArray`, only the `marks` field in each struct retains the value. The `name` and `ID` are shown to be some random garbage value.

The iteration code is standard. Nevertheless, here it is.

```
   for(i = 0; i < no_of_batches; i++)   {
        currBSize = BatchArray[i].n;
        printf("Batch %d\n", (i+1));
        printf("Batch size %d\n", currBSize);
        for(j = 0; j < currBSize; j++)  {
            puts(BatchArray[i].stud_array[j].name);
        }
    }
```

The problem that I'm working on needs to find the average marks of each batch, so that's not a problem. But I'd like to know why the other fields get reset to garbage values.

Can someone help with this?

Edit : here is how I'm populating the fields.

The file consists of entries like this

3
Name1 ID1 marks1
Name2 ID2 marks2
Name3 ID3 marks3
2
Name4 ID4 marks4
Name5 ID5 marks5

and this is the code.

```
no_of_batches = 0;
            infileptr = fopen (infilename, "r");

            BatchArray = (Batch *) malloc(sizeof(no_of_batches));

            int MAX_BUFF = 100;
            char currLine[MAX_BUFF];    

            while (fgets(currLine, MAX_BUFF, infileptr) != NULL)    {

                no_of_batches++;
                BatchArray = (Batch *) realloc(BatchArray, no_of_batches*sizeof(Batch));
                currBatchSize = atoi(currLine);
                BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].n = currBatchSize;
                printf("currBatchSize : %d\n",BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].n);
                BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array = (Student *) malloc(currBatchSize*sizeof(Student));
                for(i = 0; i < currBatchSize; i++)  {
                    fgets(currLine, MAX_BUFF, infileptr);
                    currLine[strlen(currLine)-1] = '\0';

                    BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].details = currLine;

                    //getting the Name from currLine
                    j = 0;
                    len = strlen(currLine);
                    char buildName[len];
                    while(currLine[j] != ' ')   {
                        buildName[j] = currLine[j];
                        j++;
                    }

                    buildName[j] = '\0';
                    BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].name = buildName;

                    j++;
                    //getting the ID from currLine
                    k = 0;
                    char buildID[len];
                    while(currLine[j] != ' ')   {
                        buildID[k] = currLine[j];
                        j++;
                        k++;
                    }

                    buildID[k] = '\0';
                    BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].ID = buildID;

                    puts(BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].name);
                    puts(BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].ID);

                    //getting the marks from currLine
                    k = 0;
                    j++;
                    char buildMarks[len];
                    while(currLine[j] != '\0')  {
                        buildMarks[k] = currLine[j];
                        j++;
                        k++;
                    }

                    buildMarks[k] = '\0';
                    BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].marks = atoi(buildMarks);
                    printf("%d\n",BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].marks);
                }
                puts("");
            }
```

Comment: Are you using `malloc` for the `char*` or are you using a locally defined array of char?

Comment: Please add the declaration of BatchArray and where its members are loaded, esp. where space is allocated for the char strings pointed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
    BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].name = buildName;
```

write

```
    BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].name = strdup(buildName);
```

The problem with the first case is that `name` points to `buildName`, which is an array on the stack and will be overwritten whenever the contents of the stack change.

In the second case you've copied the array to newly allocated heap memory (as with `malloc` or `realloc`), which will remain unmodified until you `free` it.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are not allocating memory for `name` and `ID` fields. Since both name and ID fields are char pointers, you need to allocate memory for each of them seperately before populating them.

If you post the code where you are populating the fields, SO people will be able to give you a more accurate reason.

EDIT:

You are using the same local variables buildName and buildID for populating different student's values. When you assign the local variables to your structure fields, what is stored in them are the address of those variables, the values in those addressess keep changing as you iterate through the loop. The other problem is that local variables go out of scope once you return from the function. So, it is suggested to use either malloc for allocating memory for name and ID fields or use strdup (You can refer to ectamur's answer below on using strdup).

Comment: I have edited the question and added the relevant working code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The field `name` and `ID` are of type `char*`, that is they are pointers. If between the load and the iteration the memory they point to is overwritten, then they point to garbage. In this case it appears that you assign the field `name` to the starting address of the  `buildName` array that, being a local variable, is allocated onto the stack.

You have two alternatives:

- Change the fields type into array of chars. The drawback is that you have to specify a maximum length and check for buffer overflow.
- Use dynamic memory. You can use dynamic memory by using `strdup` or `malloc`. In this case, you have to deallocate (by calling `free`) when the memory is no more needed, to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: How is my code different from what your second alternative is? Thanks.

Comment: You use dynamic memory on the array of `Student`, but you have to use it also for the arrays of chars `name` and `ID`, instead of using the local memory provided by `buildName` and `buildID`.

Comment: I put `BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].name = (char *) malloc(strlen(buildName)*sizeof(char));` before the `BatchArray[no_of_batches-1].stud_array[i].name = buildName;` statement. Didn't seem to help. Same garbage values.

Comment: After doing the malloc, you need to do copy the string into the newly allocated memory by doing a strcpy. Only then it will work.